# How to make watermark always floating above the screen in MacOS

Tags: ios, swift, macos, cocoa

I want to make an application that will add a watermark to the live screen on MacOS,and watermark should always floating above other app .
I defined a custom, transparent, window. It works perfectly except in following cases:  fullscreen mode,Mission Control Combination key down,Show Desktop Combination key down.

1. Since it doesn’t work when other app in full screenmode,so is that possible to disable other app in full screenmode
2. I notice that NSWindowLevel and CGWindowLevelKey，Anyone know how to use for my situation?
3. Is that other ways to make this app floating above other app by use other API?
   I have attached my implementation for your reference, with the following codes then watermark window could float above other windows.

[attached screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/maB5e.png)

[Click here to download my project](http://lc-ff0h7lm6.cn-n1.lcfile.com/fc35df4d617be23b337d/watermark.zip)

```
class WaterMarkWindow: NSWindow {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.level = .floating;
        self.ignoresMouseEvents = true;
        self.isReleasedWhenClosed = false;
        self.isMovableByWindowBackground = false;
        self.alphaValue = 0.3
        self.backgroundColor = NSColor.clear;
        self.isOpaque = false;
        self.hasShadow = false;
        self.contentView?.wantsLayer = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: For full screen the window is moved to new space so it can't be above any window because it's the only window in space. For other try kCGMaximumWindowLevel or kCGCursorWindowLevel

Comment: Is it possible for games run with OpenGL?

Comment: @任景开 I have a similar problem. Have you already found a solution? Thanks!

Comment: Did you have any success with this? Is your application available to download somewhere?